# Connecting to MYSQL AWS-RDS using SQLAlchemy in Pycharm/ with Python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

[Click to see RDS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXwH3.png)
Im trying to connect to a MYSQL server on Amazons Web Service, specifically the RDS- using SQLAlchemy in python (Pycharm).

I've already installed drivers for pymysql to include in the connection string for the engine (engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://...).
I've tried setting the CIDR security group inbound and outbound rules to allow any IP.
I can connect to the AWS-RDS just fine from MYSQL Workbench suing the Endpoint, Port and credentials.
I was able to connect to a local instance of MYSQL using SQLAlchemy and create_engine(...) without any issues too.
I've tried including and excluding the port from the URL.

```
try:          # exception handling for database creation/ existence
    engine = create_engine(link_to_db, pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=3600)   # Access the DB Engine
    connection = engine.connect()
    print("Database conn 1 successful")
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e)
    print("error connecting to db")
```

where link_to_db is "mysql+pymysql://{RDS USERNAME}:{RDS PASSWORD}@
{RDS ENDPOINT}:3306/{DATABASE NAME}"

The expected result is 
"Database conn 1 successful" 
printed to the output.

Errors :
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '{RDS URL}' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was as simple as changing from a multiline string """ {link} """ to single quotes '{link}'.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the below things.

```
1) Check your rds is publicly accessible to YES. if its in private subnet check connectivity between your source(office/home/etc) to destination(RDS).
2) open 3306 in the security group.
3) check master user credentials. 

# telnet {rds end-point} 3306
```

Comment: It is publicly accessible. 
I'm not quite sure what you mean by open 3306 in the security group.
The username and password is exactly as I have it in the MYSQL workbench which does successfully connect which is why i'm sure that's not the issue.

Comment: Ok run this command - telnet yourrdsendpoint 3306 . 3306 is MySQL default port and that should be open in rds security group to connect your office/home network. Search how to open 3306 port in rds security group and then run above command. If it's succeeded then you will be able to access the rds if not then you need to check on vpc level.

Comment: where should i run the command?
In my security group the type is set to all traffic the protocol is all, the port is all, and the source is anywhere (0.0.0.0/0, ::/0).

Comment: From your program or from cli